# Qual è il significato di "cinquantesimo" in questo contesto?

Tags: word-meaning

Nel romanzo *La malora*, di Beppe Fenoglio, ho letto:

> Venne anche Tobia, e a lui domandai cos’era quel pezzo di carta che aveva sul petto, che a me sembrava la vendetta scritta di qualcuno; era invece il ricordino del **cinquantesimo** di messa del parroco di Trezzo, e secondo Tobia Costantino doveva aver pensato di metterselo sul cuore per farsi perdonare in parte da nostro Signore.

Nella voce "cinquantesimo" che ho trovato in alcuni dizionari non ho visto niente che faccia riferimento alla messa. Per questa ragione vi chiedo: sapreste spiegarmi cosa significa "cinquantesimo" nel brano sopra citato?

Comment: Per un sacerdote cattolico, la prima messa è un evento che fa tutt'uno con l'ordinazione; la messa è solenne e, almeno un tempo, cantata. L'anniversario dell'ordinazione e della prima messa è analogo a quello di matrimonio per una coppia.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Cinquantesimo     qui si riferisce ad un anniversario,  probabilmente alla celebrazione dei cinquant’anni di sacerdozio del parroco di Trezzo.

Solo come esempio:

> [Grande festa per il 50^ anniversario di Sacerdozio del Parroco don Aurelio Ricci](http://www.diocesisora.it/pdigitale/grande-festa-50-anniversario-sacerdozio-del-parroco-don-aurelio-ricci/)

Comment: Spiegazione alternativa (ma che mi convince solo fino a un certo punto): è il ricordo della cinquantesima messa celebrata.

Comment: @RiccardoDeContardi - mmm, I preti dicono migliaia di messe.  Celebrare la   cinquantesima non ha molto senso...te lo dice un ex chierichetto :)

Comment: Un’altra possibile alternativa invece, potrebbe essere 50 anni di sevizio presso la stessa parrocchia. Cosa rara ma possibile. http://blog.ilgiornale.it/spirli/2017/11/07/parroco-da-guinness-50-anni-nella-stessa-parrocchia/ - comunque propendo per la prima ipotesi.

Comment: Sono d'accordo con @Gio. Semmai è l'anniversario della prima volta che il parroco di Trezzo aveva celebrato la messa.

Comment: E cos'è questo accento circonflesso?

Comment: Toglierei il “probabilmente”.

Comment: @Charo Certi adoperavano `^` sulla macchina per scrivere per indicare un ordinale; non c'erano modi molto migliori. Al giorno d'oggi fa ridere.

Comment: @egreg: Quindi è un po' come come gli apostrofi al posto degli accenti, che ancora si usano ([questa copertina del Touring Club editore](http://www.touringclubstore.com/it/prodotto/piemonte-14244) per esempio usa tutte i due i sistemi nella stessa frase). Curioso...

Comment: Tuttavia, ho visto in [questo articolo dell'Accademia della Crusca](http://www.accademiadellacrusca.it/en/italian-language/language-consulting/questions-answers/guida-alluso-accenti-apostrofi-nellitaliano) che c'è controversia su questo pie' o piè. Quindi, lasciamo perdere.